# Grant admin access to Outlook add-in from non admin login

Tags: visual-studio, outlook-addin

I have developed a small outlook add-in using VS 2010 and InstallShield. The plugin scans email content while composing the email and allows or blocks the sending of email based on some keywords. 
This plugin was configured to install as "PER MACHINE" and installed through admin login
while blocking, plugin creates a text log of that action. Currently, The log file is created in C:\Program data\addin.log. 
But non admin users are able to edit this log file. 
Is there a way, to configure the plugin, to create a log in a location which cant be accessed by non-admin users ?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the installer to create a log file in the Application Data folder of the user. Thus, a log file will be created in the admin's profile and non-admin users will not be able to access it without granted privileges.

You may find the [Deploying an Office Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx) section in MSDN helpful.

Comment: Initially, I configured the log in %appdata% folder. But the path is user specific correct? You want me create the log in appdata folder of admin for all users ? will that work for non admin log in?

Comment: Yes, it will work for all users. Each user will have its own log file.

Comment: Will users be able to edit that log file? Sorry.. i am not in position to test myself..

Comment: Only a user for whom the file was created. And administrators, of course.